# Arguments are not passing from component to actions when using redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using Redux-saga, so that I can fetch items from my API side. I have initialized my saga middleware in the index page as per the instruction given in the [redux-saga documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).

The following snippet is my `/src/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import reducer from './reducers';
import App from './root-components/app';

export const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <App />
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My component is `src/component/index.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { sagaMiddleWare } from '../index.js';
import { fetchPrescriptionsFromUrl } from '../actions/presAction';

class Index extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    const res = "434566ytui87unhygt99";
    sagaMiddleware.run(fetchPrescriptionsFromUrl);
    fetchPrescriptionsFromUrl(res); 
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1> My First Component </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Index;
```

I am calling action `fetchPrescriptionsFromUrl(res)` passing the parameter `res` along with it. My action is `presAction` is

```
import {call, put} from "redux-saga/effects";
import  axios from 'axios';

const getCharacters = (accessPoint) => {
  axios.get(accessPoint)
}

export function *fetchPrescriptionsFromUrl(accessToken){
  console.log('AT', accessToken)
  try {
    const response = yield call(getCharacters(accessToken))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

On `console.log` of argument which is been passed from the component `index.jsx` is stated as `undefined`.

I am beginner in `redux-saga`, don't know where am making error. It will be helpful if I got any solutions for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for editing @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Redux Saga  call function cannot be used this way. It should look like this

```
const response = yield call(getCharacters, accessToken)
```

In your case `getCharacters` was evaluated imidiatelly and it's result was passed into `call`

Also you shouldn't use sagaMiddleWare in your Index component. Point of (not just saga) middleware is that you dispatch actions as normal and then catch concrete actions in your middleware

Comment: Then, how to pass `accessToken` Sir. Is there any other way of doing it. Or is there any other example can I follow?